# Keyboard layout for math

Tags: macos, keyboard, internationalization, latex, unicode

I usually need to write math with LaTeX, and after seeing this question: [Entering unicode math symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110042/entering-unicode-math-symbols-into-latex-direct-from-keyboard-on-a-mac). I came here with some small questions.

I find that not perfectly comfortable, and I was wondering if there is a way in which I could tell the system to differentiate between the left and right <kbd>alt ⌥</kbd>. So I could have much more symbols within one *letter*.

And, the another question is if there is a way I could turn the <kbd>caps lock ⇪</kbd> into a different key (with the same use as <kbd>alt ⌥</kbd>, but the system should differentiate them). In this way I could use, for instance,

- <kbd>caps lock ⇪</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to get the greek letters (in this case the letter delta `δ`), and
- <kbd>alt ⌥</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to get some math symbol of my decision (in this case the *partial differential symbol* `∂`).

This is not a great example, but more or less self explaining. Of course then <kbd>caps lock ⇪</kbd> shouldn't be a turn on/turn off button. It should be *turned on* ONLY when pressed (exactly like <kbd>alt ⌥</kbd>).

Comment: I haven't gotten either of those to work with just keylayout files, but [my answer to the question cross-posted at Super User](http://superuser.com/a/593142/69039) describes workarounds using KeyRemap4MacBook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is all possible. In my [answer on TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110042/entering-unicode-math-symbols-into-latex-direct-from-keyboard-on-a-mac/110043#110043), I give the [MathUnicode.keylayout](http://pastebin.com/agQYq4AZ) file that I made. Essentially, my advice is: go ahead and play around with this file.

A couple of thoughts:

- The XML specification for `.keylayout` files is [available from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2056/_index.html).
- On line 22 you can see that I refer to the `anyOption` modifier. This refers to the left or right option key. But you can also write `option` or `rightOption` if you wish to distinguish between the two.
- I'm not sure whether caps can be treated as a "hold down" key, as you want it, rather than a "press on / press off" key.

Comment: Well, that's an advance. Thank you. Probably what I want most is the caps as a hold on, since I almost never use it, and differentiating between right/left options could be messy.